# orderBy doesn't seem to work after editing result values in angular

Tags: angularjs

I wrote this directive editable-field to be able to edit values after the form search results.

```
<table>..
<tr ng-repeat="emp in srchCtrl.emps | orderBy : 'salary'">
        <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
        <td editable-field="emp.name"></td>
        <td editable-field="emp.salary"></td>
        <td editable-field="emp.department.name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After I change the value, the values change, but, how can I ask angular to refresh results with orderBy filter using new values?

```
.controller('MainController')..
var self = this;
self.emps = [ ]; // this will be populated after the promise resolves.

}
```

I see the emps getting updated by printing them.

```
.directive('editableField', function () {
    var self = this || {};
    self.link = function (scope, elm, attr, editCtrl) {
        var previousValue;
    editCtrl.edit = function () {
        editCtrl.editMode = true;
        previousValue = editCtrl.model;
        elm.find('input')[0].focus();
    };
    editCtrl.save = function () {
        editCtrl.editMode = false;
    };
    editCtrl.cancel = function () {
        editCtrl.editMode = false;
        editCtrl.model = previousValue;
    };
}
return {
    scope: {},
    controllerAs: 'editCtrl',
    controller: function () {
    },
    bindToController: {
        model: '=editableField'
    },
    link: self.link,
    templateUrl: '../../../templates/row-edit.html'
};
})
```

This is my editableField directive which binds editableField field on the row to the model in the controller which is editCtrl.

On save I am calling the callback function on the main controller which has reference to the emps

If I call scope.$apply() in any of the editCtrl's save, it says "$apply already in progress"

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(self, function () {
                        return self.emps; // `this` IS the `this` above!!
                    }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
                        // now we will pickup changes to newVal and oldVal
                        if (newVal === oldVal) { console.log('first time'); return; } // AKA first run
                        console.log('self.emps updated');
                    });
```

I see the value getting updated on changing values in the UI.

```
 scope.$watch(angular.bind(editCtrl, function () {
                                return editCtrl.model;
                            }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
                                if (newVal === oldVal) { console.log('model first time'+newVal); return; }
                                console.log('model updated');
                            });
```

Comment: $apply() or $digest()?

Comment: A description of your **editable-field** directive would be helpful

Comment: maybe just because type became string after edit，i tested with ng-repeat and ng-model, when i log value out i got `["2", "1", 21, 21, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

Your ***editable-field*** directive should have something like the following:

```
scope: {
    "emp": "="
}
```

So that a change in the passed value to **editable-field** is reflected back to the parent ***Controller / Directive***.